# Is movie gear avilable for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-sources, animations

Back in windows I have used [Movie gear](http://www.gamani.com/product_animated.htm) to crate GIF files.
I would like to know wheather it is availble in Ubuntu.
If not please list out similar softwares.

Comment: If the vendor does not have a download for it, them chances are that it's not available for Ubuntu. I use GIMP (sudo apt-get install gimp) to make GIFs - you just make each frame an individual layer, export to GIF, then select the 'As animation' option in the following dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the page for the program, no.

Instead, I would use GIMP - it allows you to create GIF files. You make each frame an individual layer, and then you export to GIF, and select "As animation" in the export dialog.

(Install)

```
sudo apt-get install gimp
```